# Having an issue with Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

```
MATCH (n:CALLS { compileunit:'Way-Duy_User-Task-Manager.2020-11-12.java', release:1})-[*]->(b)  
set n.szDet_t = sum(b.szDet)
return n, sum(b.szDet) as DET
```

The above mentioned code is not working, although similar lines are functioning perfectly.

This gets the right value but does NOT update det.

```
MATCH (n:CALLS { compileunit:'Way-Duy_User-Task-Manager.2020-11-12.java', release:1})-[*]->(b)  
return n.Label, sum(b.szDet) as DET
```

I would appreciate help in getting this to work. This is Neo4j cypher.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, using sum() in a SET does not work.

You have to insert a WITH :

```
WITH n, sum(b.szDet) AS DET
SET n.szDet_t = DET
```

should work